# Calling methods a la Object#send, but not breaking when given a nonexistent method (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, send

I'm trying to do something like this in Ruby with the `send` method:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "Foo's bar method"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.send :bar # => "Foo's bar method"
foo.send :baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method `baz' for #<Foo:0x00000000a2e720>
              # Is there a way I can send :baz to foo without the program breaking?
              # I.e., don't call anything if the given method doesn't exist.
```

Obviously, passing in the nonexistent `:baz` returns an error, but I'm wondering if there's a way to call methods that do exist, in a `send`-like way, and for methods passed in that don't exist, I'm just wanting the program not to break. Does anyone know of something that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [method_missing](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/method_missing)

```
def respond_to_missing?(*)
  true
end

private

def method_missing(*)
end
```

This will make your object to return `nil` in response to any undefined method.

For more powerful way to implement kind of NullObject pattern take look at the [naught](https://github.com/avdi/naught) gem by Avdi Grimm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails, you might try looking at [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)